# CopyBooks,.cpy files,WTX Design Studio

Tags: cobol, copybook, wtx

I am working on WTX design Studio with copybooks,i have a copybook but i dont have any corresponding sample input regarding that .cpy file .

Are there any means to generate a  sample text file from copy book rather than writing the text document manually?

Comment: Lots of ways, but it depends what you have access to. Easiest, actually using the copybook, is for you to do it in a small COBOL program.

Answer (score 1):

As bill said there are lots of ways depending on the tools available:

1. **Ask** for sample file
2. There are **packages** that can **generate data**. As I do not work at your site I do not know if any have been installed. They tend to be expensive though
3. Write a **Cobol program** (I presume the source is a mainframe) so it would have to be done on the mainframe.
4. I presume the source is a Mainframe, get on the Mainframe and use **FileAid** (or **FileMaster** or whatever they have) to setup the file. **FileAid** and its ilk let you edit files with a Cobol copybook.
5. Use the [RecordEditor](http://record-editor.sourceforge.net/) to create the file. You can import Cobol Copybooks into the RecordEditor and then use them to edit Cobol-Data files.
6. Use a [RecordEditor](http://record-editor.sourceforge.net/) macro to generate a file;
7. Write a Java / jython / JRuby program with Cobol interface package (have a look on sourceforge)
8. There are a lot of other possibilities, as I do not know what software or skills you have I can not really advise.

---

RecordEditor Macro to generate some numeric data:

```
  /******************************************************************
   * Purpose: RecordEditor Example Macroto generate numeric data for a file
   * 
   *  It is best to run this script from a Single Record Screen rather than 
   * a Table screen
   *
   *******************************************************************/     
 var rec = layout.getRecord(0)

 var lines = RecordEditorData.view.createLines(20)
 for (lineNo = 0; lineNo < 20; lineNo++) {
    print(lineNo);
    for (i=0; i < rec.getFieldCount(); i++) {
        try {
            lines[lineNo].getFieldValue(0, i).set(lineNo * 100 + i) 
        } catch(err) {
            lines[lineNo].getFieldValue(0, i).set(i % 10)   
        }
    }
 }

 RecordEditorData.view.addLines(-1,1, lines)
```

Output from the Macro:

[image]